# Am I too tall to bother modifying my old trek?

Tags: road-bike, frames, modification, tall

I bought an old Trek 500 series road bike a couple months ago and have put love and parts into it but it's just too damn small for me (I'm 6'4"). All the post adjustments are at their safest limits. Are there mods or extensions worth buying to make it more comfortable/efficient or would it be cheaper/easier just to sell it to a short person and find a bigger framed bike? Thanks, J

Comment: I'm about your height, and rode a too-small MTB for a couple years by using an extended seatpost... until the frame cracked.   By far the best thing you can do is get a bike that is big enough.  Pass the old one on to family or relatives or friends/kids if it has meaning for you, or sell it to offset the costs of a new bike.  You're obviously into riding in a good way, shout yourself a new one.

Answer (score 8):

If you adjust a bike to the max and its still significantly too small, you should sell the bike and get a new bike.

There are extra long seatposts, and extra long quill stems and what not, but in all likelihood its not really worth it if the bike doesn't fit with the normal seatpost + stem; the other parts of geometry like top tube length are probably too small anyway.